# Unexpected behavior of the fn.AVG peewee function

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I'm working on a project to explore covid-19 cases using python and peewee as a learning exercise.

There are two tables involved in this question:

The Domain model describes worldwide regions down to the county level granularity for the US. For exanple, there is a row for New York county which contains the fields Domain.country_region = 'US', Domain.province_state = 'New York', Domain.admin2 = 'New York'.

The Confirmed model contains the cumulative count of confirmed covid-19 cases since earlier this year for each domain.

The immediate goal is to calculate the 5-day rolling average of cases for each domain. Eventually I plan to be able to identify developments of interest in counties and states such as "spikes", etc.

Below I include the models, a test script and the output of the script. I'm using a subquery to compute the daily count of cases because I was not able to create calculated columns that use other calculated columns in the same table row.

The problem is that in the "q" query, fn.AVG is not calculating the average of the last 5 days of daily confirmed cases but it returns the value of the last day (6/19/2020).

I was about to try using hybrid properties in the Confirmed table instead of this approach, but I'm curious as to why this code does not work.

Models (only the relevant tables are listed):

```
from peewee import *
db = SqliteDatabase('data/covid.db')
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
class Domain(BaseModel):
    uid = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    country_region = CharField()
    province_state = CharField(default='')
    admin2 = CharField(default='')
    population = IntegerField(default=0)
    area = FloatField(default=0.0)
    density = FloatField(default=0.0)
class Confirmed(BaseModel):
    uid = ForeignKeyField(Domain)
    date = DateField()
    count = IntegerField()
```

The complete code:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
from covid.models import *
from datetime import date

subq = (Domain
    .select(
        Domain.uid,
        Domain.country_region,
        Domain.province_state,
        Domain.admin2,
        Confirmed.date,
        Confirmed.count,
        (Confirmed.count - fn.LAG(Confirmed.count, 1)
            .over(
                partition_by=[Domain.country_region, Domain.province_state,
                    Domain.admin2],
                order_by=[Confirmed.date],
            )
        ).alias('daily')
    )
    .join(Confirmed, on=(Domain.uid == Confirmed.uid))
    .where(
          (Domain.country_region == 'US')
        & (Domain.province_state == 'New York')
        & (Domain.admin2 == 'New York')
    )
    .order_by(
        Domain.country_region,
        Domain.province_state,
        Domain.admin2,
        Confirmed.date
    )
).alias('subq')

# -------------------------------------------

q = (Domain
        .select(
            subq.c.province_state,
            subq.c.admin2,
            subq.c.date,
            subq.c.count,
            subq.c.daily,
            fn.AVG(subq.c.daily)
                .over(
                    start=Window.preceding(4), end=Window.preceding(0),
                    partition_by=[subq.c.country_region, subq.c.province_state,
                        subq.c.admin2],
                    order_by=[subq.c.date]
                )
                .alias('avg5'),
        )
        .join(subq, on=(Domain.uid == subq.c.uid))
        .where(subq.c.date == date(2020,6,19))
    )

print('--------------------------------- subq')
print(subq)
print(tabulate(subq.dicts(), 'keys'))

print('--------------------------------- q')
print(q)
print(tabulate(q.dicts(), 'keys'))
```

... and the output:

```
--------------------------------- subq
SELECT "t1"."uid", "t1"."country_region", "t1"."province_state", "t1"."admin2", "t2"."date", 
"t2"."count", ("t2"."count" - LAG("t2"."count", 1) OVER (PARTITION BY "t1"."country_region", 
"t1"."province_state", "t1"."admin2" ORDER BY "t2"."date")) AS "daily" FROM "domain" AS "t1"
INNER JOIN "confirmed" AS "t2" ON ("t1"."uid" = "t2"."uid_id") 
WHERE ((("t1"."country_region" = 'US') AND ("t1"."province_state" = 'New York')) 
AND ("t1"."admin2" = 'New York')) 
ORDER BY "t1"."country_region", "t1"."province_state", "t1"."admin2", "t2"."date"
     uid  country_region    province_state    admin2    date          count    daily
--------  ----------------  ----------------  --------  ----------  -------  -------
84036061  US                New York          New York  2020-01-22        0
84036061  US                New York          New York  2020-01-23        0        0
84036061  US                New York          New York  2020-01-24        0        0
...
84036061  US                New York          New York  2020-06-13   209493      539
84036061  US                New York          New York  2020-06-14   209878      385
84036061  US                New York          New York  2020-06-15   210259      381
84036061  US                New York          New York  2020-06-16   210591      332
84036061  US                New York          New York  2020-06-17   210941      350
84036061  US                New York          New York  2020-06-18   211260      319
84036061  US                New York          New York  2020-06-19   211670      410
--------------------------------- q
SELECT "subq"."province_state", "subq"."admin2", "subq"."date", "subq"."count", "subq"."daily", 
AVG("subq"."daily") OVER (PARTITION BY "subq"."country_region", "subq"."province_state", 
"subq"."admin2" ORDER BY "subq"."date" ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING) AS "avg5" FROM 
"domain" AS "t1" INNER JOIN (SELECT "t1"."uid", "t1"."country_region", "t1"."province_state", 
"t1"."admin2", "t2"."date", "t2"."count", ("t2"."count" - LAG("t2"."count", 1) OVER (PARTITION BY 
"t1"."country_region", "t1"."province_state", "t1"."admin2" ORDER BY "t2"."date")) AS "daily" FROM 
"domain" AS "t1" INNER JOIN "confirmed" AS "t2" ON ("t1"."uid" = "t2"."uid_id") WHERE 
((("t1"."country_region" = 'US') AND ("t1"."province_state" = 'New York')) AND ("t1"."admin2" = 'New 
York')) ORDER BY "t1"."country_region", "t1"."province_state", "t1"."admin2", "t2"."date") AS "subq" 
ON ("t1"."uid" = "subq"."uid") WHERE ("subq"."date" = '2020-06-19')
province_state    admin2    date          count    daily    avg5
----------------  --------  ----------  -------  -------  ------
New York          New York  2020-06-19   211670      410     410
```

Comment: Rather than try to parse-out all that, do you instead have a working SQL query we can use as the starting point? I think you may have an issue with the SQL, in other words.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have equivalent SQL. However I  redefined my problem and posted a greatly simplified runnable script in a new  question titled "How do I create a virtual column equal to the difference between two previous values of another column in peewee?" a few minutes ago. Please take a look at that question where I try to compute the difference between the values of two rows in a column so that I can calculate the average by dividing the difference by the number of rows.